# Javascript: Convert string to array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, type-conversion

Tell me, how can I optimally convert a string like

```
const data = "1350, 1351, 1390-1391, 1401, 1402 - 1407";
```

to an array like

```
const range = [
    {
        min: 1350,
        max: 1350,
    },
    {
        min: 1351,
        max: 1351,
    },
    {
        min: 1390,
        max: 1391,
    },
    {
        min: 1401,
        max: 1401,
    },
    {
        min: 1402,
        max: 1407,
    },
];
```

?

In other words, you need to create an array of number ranges using a string in which these numbers ranges are explicitly specified.

The most obvious of the possible algorithms is:

1) split the string using a delimiter`,`

2) the resulting parts are cleaned of spaces using the command `trim`

3) check whether the part is a number

4) if not, then split the part using the delimiter `-`

5) the parts obtained are cleaned of spaces using the command `trim`,

6) check that the amount of component eq 2 and it's a number

But is it possible to make it more optimal, more beautiful, more effective?

Comment: Zhihar, it's working for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.split()` and `.map()`:

```js
const data = "1350, 1351, 1390-1391, 1401, 1402 - 1407";

const range = data.split(",").map(s => {
  let [min, max = min] = s.split("-");

  return {min: Number(min), max: Number(max)}
});

console.log(range);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
const data = "1350, 1351, 1390-1391, 1401, 1402 - 1407"

const result = data
  .split(/\s*,\s*/)
  .map(pair => {
    const [min, max = min] = pair
      .split(/\s*-\s*/)
      .map(Number)

    return {
      min,
      max
    }
  })

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `+` operator or `Number` constructor in order to force values to be numerical.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut ah, right, didn't notice, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` method in combination with `reduce` method.

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Also, use `+` operator in order to **force** result to `Number`.

```js
const data = "1350, 1351, 1390-1391, 1401, 1402 - 1407";
const array = data.split(', ').reduce(function(arr, elem){
   var [min, max] = elem.split('-');
   arr.push({
      min : + min,
      max: + (max || min)
   });
   return arr;
},[]);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple and much understandable way would be to loop through the values and check if they have a range value (with hyphen) and create the object accordingly for the `range` array.

```js
const data = "1350, 1351, 1390-1391, 1401, 1402 - 1407";
var range = [];
data.split(',').forEach((val)=>{
  var obj = {};
  if(val.indexOf('-') === -1 ){
    obj.min = val;
    obj.max = val;
  } else {
    obj.min = val.split('-')[0].trim();
    obj.max = val.split('-')[1].trim();
  }
  range.push(obj);
});

console.log(range);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```js
const data = "1350, 1351, 1390-1391, 1401, 1402 - 1407";
var arr = data.split(',');
const range = [];
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
var b = arr[i].split('-');
if(!b[1])b[1]=b[0];
var obj = new Object();
obj.min = parseInt(b[0]);
obj.max = parseInt(b[1]);
range.push(obj);
}
console.log(range);
```